Accessing object property dynamically using a union type as key
User object can have different types of social media accounts (email, google, twitter), and each type stores the username in a unique key (address for email, name for Google, and username for X (formerly known as Twitter)). I am attempting to dynamically retrieve the username for a given social type by passing the type as a parameter to a function.
interface Email {
  address: string;
}
interface Google {
  name: string;
}
interface Twitter {
  username: string;
}

interface User {
  email?: Email;
  google?: Google;
  twitter?: Twitter;
}
function getUsername(social: "email" | "google" | "twitter", user: User) {
  const userUsernames = {
    email: "address",
    google: "name",
    twitter: "username",
  } as const;
  const socialAccount = user[social];

  const username = socialAccount ? socialAccount[userUsernames[social]] : null;
  return username
}

But I am getting

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"address" | "name" | "username"' can't be used to index type 'Email | Google | Twitter'

I am aware that I could use if statements or a switch case to handle type-specific property access, but I am exploring if there's a way to achieve this dynamically in TypeScript without explicitly checking each type. How can this be done while ensuring type safety?

• Please [edit] your code to use conventional type names like Email instead of unconventional ones like email. • This is an instance of ms/TS#30581 and the only supported way to do this "while ensuring type safety" the way you presumably mean it is to refactor to generics as described in ms/TS#47109; see this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Thanks @jcalz, the code above is not exactly my case but a simple example to reproduce the issue. Is there a way to do it without changing the User type since in my case it's exported by a library, otherwise can I add more fields to the User type ?

You don't have to change the existing type, but you do have to use a different type to let TS know how to understand it. See this playground link; nothing stops you from passing a value of your library's User type to the getUsername function. So, does this fully address the question now? If so I could write an answer, if not, what am I still missing?

Yes, that should answer my question thanks.

TypeScript can't deal directly with "correlated union types", where you have a union-typed value, like social, appear multiple times in the same expression , like user[social][userUsernames[social]]. TypeScript will treat each utterance of social as being independently of type "email" | "google" | "twitter", so for all it can tell, it's like you've written user[social1][userUsernames[social2]] where social1 might not equal social2.  It doesn't have the ability to analyze the single expression once for each possible member of typeof social.  This limitation is described in detail in microsoft/TypeScript#30581.
If you want TypeScript to follow logic like this, you need to switch from unions to generics, in a particular way as detailed in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. Your operations will have to be written in terms of: a "base" key-value mapping type; mapped types over that base type; and generic indexes into those types.  The goal is that the compiler will see your operations as a single generic type manipulation, instead of multiple cases.
For your example code that could look like this:
interface UsernameMap {
  email: "address";
  google: "name";
  twitter: "username";
}

function getUsername<K extends keyof UsernameMap>(
  social: K,
  user: { [K in keyof UsernameMap]?: Record<UsernameMap[K], string> }
) {
  const userUsernames: UsernameMap = {
    email: "address",
    google: "name",
    twitter: "username",
  };
  const socialAccount = user[social];
  const username = socialAccount ? socialAccount[userUsernames[social]] : null;
  return username
}

declare const user: User
const username = getUsername("email", user); // this works

The UsernameMap type is the base key-value mapping, representing the core relationship you care about.  Then getUsername() is generic in K, corresponding to the type of social.  And now the type of user is written as a mapped type over UsernameMap. This type is assignable from User, so you can still pass in a User as the second argument to getUsername. Finally, the type of userUsernames is annotated as UsernameMap.  Now all the operations work because: user[social] is seen as type Record<UsernameMap[K], string> | undefined; userUsernames[social] is seen as type UsernameMap[K], and if user[social] is not undefined, then you can index into it with userUsernames[social] to get a string.
Note that these type representations are important. Even if User is equivalent to { [K in keyof UsernameMap]?: Record<UsernameMap[K], string> }, you can't write User instead for the type of user without breaking things. It's the fact that everything is written explicitly in terms of UsernameMap that ties it together.
Playground link to code
